# Python package import: urllib3 version conflict

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to import sagemaker from AWS. This has worked fine before, but all of a sudden there is a package dependency.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deepar_batch_transform.py", line 13, in <module>
    import sagemaker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from sagemaker import estimator, parameter, tuner  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py", line 29, in <module>
    from sagemaker.analytics import TrainingJobAnalytics
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/analytics.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sagemaker.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 34, in <module>
    from sagemaker.user_agent import prepend_user_agent
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/user_agent.py", line 23, in <module>
    SDK_VERSION = pkg_resources.require("sagemaker")[0].version
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 972, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 863, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.25.4 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1'), {'requests'})
```

I have tried it multiple times by updating urllib3, but still am not able to access sagemaker

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.24 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.26,>=1.25.4; python_version != "3.4"'), {'botocore'})
```

Also

```
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.25 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1'), {'requests'})
```

Any ideas on how i can resolve this?

Comment: That error indicates you need to downgrade urllib3, not upgrade. Highly recommend using a virtualenv. It looks like sagemaker won't be co-installable with the version of botocore you have.